# $X_{1}=1$, $X_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+X_{n}}$, $n\geq$ Show that $\{X_{n}\}$ converges and find the limit

Tags: real-analysis

So I have to find the limit and show that $X_{n}$ converges using mathematical induction

This is what we were given in class and what I've added to the proof so far:

$X_{1}=1$, $X_{2}=\sqrt{3}$, $X_{3}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$

Let $L=\sqrt{2+L} \Rightarrow L^{2}=2+L \Rightarrow L^{2}-L-2=0 \Rightarrow (L-2)(L+1)=0$

So L can either take values 2 or -1 but since the value must be positive than we have

$X_{n} \leq X_{n+1} \leq 2$ where 2 is the upper bound

So to prove by mathematical induction you go through the case when n=1 which is true and than assume that $n=k \Rightarrow X_{k} \leq X_{k+1} \leq 2$

So when $n=k+1$ shouldn't we get $X_{k+2}=\sqrt{2+X_{k+1}}$ but this is where I get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Using $x_n \le 2,\;$ we have $x_{n+1}^2 = 2 + x_n \le 2 + 2 \le 4\;$ and therefore $x_{n+1} \le 2\;$ since $x_{n+1}\;$ is positive. Thus $\{x_n\}$ is monotone and bounded and therefore convergent. The limit $x$ can be computed from $x = \sqrt{2+x}$ or $x^2 = 2 + x\;$ and is $x=2$.

Note: The monotonicity follows from $0 \le x_n \le 2\; $ and

$$x_{n+1}^2 - x_{n}^2 = 2 + x_{n}- x_{n}^2
\ge 2x_{n}-x_{n}^2 = x_{n}(2-x_{n}) \ge 0$$